# How to use socket io with node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I have deployed an app with Heroku. I have a chat. It work fine in local but not with the online app.

index.js in my server :

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyparser = require('body-parser');
const security = require('./middleware/security');
const userRouter = require('./routes/user');
const AnnonceRouter = require('./routes/annonce');
const securityRouter = require('./routes/security');
const commentRouter = require('./routes/comment');
const mailRouter = require('./routes/mail')
const path = require('path');


const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const app = express();

const cors = require('cors');

var chat = require('https').createServer(app)
var io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(chat)

const SocketManager = require('./SocketManager')

io.on('connection', SocketManager)

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static('../client/build')); // serve the static react app
  app.use(cors());
  app.use(bodyparser.json());
  app.use(security.verifyToken);
  app.use('/annonce', AnnonceRouter);
  app.use('/user', userRouter);
  app.use('/comment', commentRouter);
  app.use('/mail', mailRouter);
  app.get(/^\/(?!api).*/, (req, res) => { // don't serve api routes to react app
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build/index.html'));
  })
  app.use('/', securityRouter);;
  console.log('Serving React App...');
};



app.listen(PORT, function () {
  console.error(`Node ${isDev ? 'dev server' : 'cluster worker '+process.pid}: listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

the file when i use it

```
const socketUrl = "https://teachonline.herokuapp.com"
export default class Layout extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        socket:null,
        user:null
      };
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        this.initSocket()
    }

    /*
    *   Connect to and initializes the socket.
    */
    initSocket = ()=>{
        const socket = io(socketUrl)

        socket.on('connect', ()=>{
            console.log("Connected");
        })

        this.setState({socket})
    }
```

I tried something different, but the result is still the same.
My request looks like that : https://teachonline.herokuapp.com/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=MpFHcqj
But i get a code 401 "Unauthorized"

If you have an idea of what am i doing wrong, i'm listening.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `PORT_CHAT`, use `PORT`.

```
const isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const PORT_CHAT = 3231;


const app = express();


const cors = require('cors');

var chat = require('https').createServer()
var io = module.exports.io = require('socket.io')(chat)

const SocketManager = require('./SocketManager')

io.on('connection', SocketManager)

chat.listen(PORT, ()=>{
    console.log("Connected to port:" + PORT);
})
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply
Sorry i should have put all the code of my index. I edit my question with the rest of my index.js. Because i use this to my app. So when i try to run like that, i got "address already in use"

Comment: Hmm... That's odd. Sorry, I'm not sure what to do there.